# how to take a UIView screenshot faster?

Tags: ios, ios6, uiview, ios7, calayer

I'm making a dictionary app, which allows user find a word definition by touch the word in screen, and there will be a magnifier on screen and follow user's finger. I have implement it by take a screenshot of view and assign the image to maginifer image view, which is a UIImageView, however, in order to take a screenshot, the method `[self.layer renderInContext:c];` cost too much time, is there any other way to do it ?maybe openGL will help?

after profiling my app with instruments->core animation, it is only 9 fps showing magnifier, but it will 30 fps if showing the system default magnifier in a UITextView, I don't know why the system is so fast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use exact same view in magnifier view, and change position to visible words.

Comment: there's a problem, If I need to make the view in maginifer larger, the I need to set the view.transform, but the origin view will be affected as well

Comment: you have to use copy of original view.

Comment: but UIView not support copy method

Comment: yourNewView=previewousView.

Answer (score 1):

There are [new methods in iOS 7](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html) that are highly optimized :

```
– snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:
– resizableSnapshotViewFromRect:afterScreenUpdates:withCapInsets:
– drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:
```

However they are not available in previous versions.